# Ocaml OCamlSpotter

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to use OCamlSpotter to browse ocaml code. I am using opam so what I did is,

%opam install spotinstall
Now I am not sure what to do exactly,

1- Have I to just make,make install?
2- No manual for the commands, any ideas how to browse the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

SpotInstall is NOT ocamlspotter. It is a helper to install binary annotation files required for code browsing for OCamlSpotter, TypeRex and other softwares.

SpotInstall's document is at its hg repo: https://bitbucket.org/camlspotter/spotinstall. It is also available as README.rst in the source.

OCamlSpotter is designed to use via Emacs (or Vim). How-to-use is roughly described at ocamlspot.el. It should be installable via opam: opam install ocamlspot. ocamlspot.el is found under your opam directory $HOME/.opam//system/lib/ocamlspot/.

If you configure OCamlSpotter config properly, move your cursor to OCaml identifiers in your OCaml source code buffer and type CTRL-c ;. If the source code is compiled with -bin-annot option, ocamlspot.el should show its definition.

Some points:

- Set your ocamlspot binary in your emacs setting (M-x customize-group => ocamlspot)
- Compile your OCaml code with -bin-annot
- See the buffer *ocamlspot-process* if you think something goes wrong.
- Submit bug reports at https://bitbucket.org/camlspotter/ocamlspot/issues?status=new&status=open , not at StackOverflow

If you use Vim users, I wrote ocamlspot.vim but it is poorly tested. Sorry but I do not use Vim.

Comment: no bugs. I opam install ocamlspot. ocamlspot.el is useless. C-c shows nothing for me.  Which tab in M-x customize-group => enter(default) => which tab? or its different sequence?